# How to add a view, above the webview, which will scroll together with it?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-scrollview

Im trying to add a a View above a webview that should scroll together with it. 
Ive tried putting both views inside a scrollview like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

It worked pretty well until Ive encountered a problem in the case that the webview changes it size after it first renders (i.e. if the loaded url uses lazy loading on some of its components).
BTW it doesn't matter if the height or width of either the scroll\Linear\Web views is set to "match_parent" or "wrap_content" I still get the same problem.

Ive also tried using the "hidden" setEmbeddedTitleBar(View v) method that was introduced and then removed from the Android's WebView, in order to simply add a view above the WebView without the need of a wrapping scroll view.
I tried some hacks that were suggested here but I didn't find something that works.

Is there anyone who encunterd this problem and had find a successful way of achieving this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: scroll of your webview and scroll of your whole activity does not interfere?

Comment: No, The scroll view handles only scroll events, all other events like pressing a link or a video in the web view works fine.

Comment: Refer to this post, http://stackoverflow.com/q/43533068/6521116

Answer (score -1):

Try adding some weights to the layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/brand_color"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```